# What is the current distribution of Stack Overflow reputation points?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Just curious as to the real distribution of Stack Overflow reputation points.
Is it the normal distribution that a social scientist might expect?

Really just looking for the actual graph as an answer.
A sufficiently large random sampling of users is all that is required.

It *should* look something like this (if it's not unnaturally skewed).
If not, a further question might be, should SO rep points be bell curved?
[image]

Comment: Um.. Jon Skeet....

Comment: Why should it be normal? I'd expect the low reps to have *significantly* higher numbers and decrease as rep gets higher.

Comment: `It should look something like this:` Why should it look like that?

Comment: Because science.

Comment: Care to elaborate on the science? It seems very unlikely that there is science that predicts the distribution of points in a complex system like this, given that the dynamics of the points system are probably very different from whatever that social scientists' curve is representing

Comment: @DominicCerisano So you don't have any reason.  Okay, good to know.

Comment: Not sure if there is a data explorer query that answers your question (but there might well be). The only thing I can think of that even comes close (but has old data and cannot be replicated in the data explorer) is Kevin Montrose's answer here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136059/revisiting-the-rep-cap-yes-again

Comment: Prolly more log-normal.

Comment: Also skewed by the 1 cutoff that prevents negative rep.

Comment: Well, the top 500 users have over 50,000,000 rep combined so I'm guessing most of the rep is going to be towards the top.  Like the Pareto principle I'd guess that the top 20% of the users have about 80% of the total rep.

Comment: Maybe someone could just post the graph and let the social scientists interpret it. SO is a social network.

Comment: @DominicCerisano generating the graph is work - why don't you do it?

Comment: @DominicCerisano - Please stop being so toxic. There are a lot of assertions made in this post which make it heavily biased, and also which attempt to demean others who are not "social scientists". That you continue to press on users for pointing them out makes it hard for the actual issue being discussed to get any attention.

Comment: "SO is a social network." OH NO YOU DIDN'T

Comment: @DominicCerisano Here is the data: https://archive.org/details/stackexchange . Let us know when you have results. Personally I expect a power law curve. Like wealth/

Comment: @DominicCerisano _"Perhaps antisocial network would have been more accurate?"_ No, _Community moderated Q&A site_ is the appropriate term.

Comment: Sorry - your attempt to get SO users to do your statistical analysis for free has failed.

Comment: @Martin and that's a feat, given how easily we can be duped into doing *loads* of work for free if just asked nicely and without condescension. Oh well.

Comment: You seem to think Stack Overflow is a social network with an "economy."  That's not accurate; it's a strictly content-focused Q&A site.  A user's Stack Overflow reputation is simply a (rough) measure of how much they've contributed.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Apparently there's no need to be nice and to remove the condescension.

Comment: @Servy yeah. But that's just how we roll. Good people, even when OPs don't deserve it... and it's arguably useful data for future readers, so.

Comment: _Insert snarky comment about homework questions here_

Comment: @johnnyRose OK - a social scientist successfully conned/engineered an SO user into doing his/her statistical analysis for their thesis, and the chances of correct attribution are less likely than a good linked-list question,

Comment: @MartinJames: I just thought it was funny that someone was asking a homework question on Meta for a change. :)

Comment: @MartinJames: On the bright side, at least SO's reputation data is finally being analyzed. Not sure why we haven't had any social scientists run analysis yet. Maybe we will finally get some answers. ;)

Comment: 'Not sure why we haven't had any social scientists run analysis yet' - because they were either technicaly incapable of it, had insufficient rep/privilege to access the data or didn't think to engineer SO slaves/drones into doing the work for them.

Comment: @user000001 Reading all the comments here, especially those of the OP, leads me to believe they aren't here to have a constructive discussion.

Answer (score 67):

Actually, it looks like this:

[image]

... when you plot it on a [log-log graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log%E2%80%93log_plot), according to [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/734355/reputation-distribution-log-log-scale#graph). The logarithms are base-10, so the 2.0 on the x-axis corresponds to 10<sup>2</sup> = 100 reputation and there are about 10<sup>4</sup> = 10,000 users with this much reputation.

Some noteworthy details:

- The first point is slightly skewed because of the many no-activity users with 1 reputation.
- The sawtooth until *x = 2* (±100 reputation) looks strange, but makes sense once you realize how hard it is to get a total reputation of 2 (1 question upvote followed by 2 downvotes).
- There's a small peak around *x = 2*, corresponding to 101 reputation; these are mainly users from other Stack Exchange sites who only have the association bonus on Stack Overflow.
- The dip indicated by the freehand arrow, from 200 to 300 reputation, is also caused by the association bonus. Users in this range either don't have other accounts on the network, or have another site where they have more reputation.
- The rightmost data point looks like an outlier, but it's [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), so in fact the rest of points in the graph are the outliers.

Also, required reading for those of you who <s>believe</s> have been taught everything can be modeled with Bell curves: [*The Black Swan: The Impact of the Highly Improbable by Nassim Nicholas Taleb*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Swan:_The_Impact_of_the_Highly_Improbable). This is a striking example of something that's not limited by (bio)physics (like body length and life expectancy), and (like wealth in the real world) best described by a power-law distribution. Alternatively, read this [Forbes article](https://www.forbes.com/sites/joshbersin/2014/02/19/the-myth-of-the-bell-curve-look-for-the-hyper-performers/#161b3d336bca) mentioned by @CodyGray in the comments.

Comment: This looks nothing like the thing he posted. You clearly have no idea how to science correctly.

Comment: But seriously - nice work! Not that the OP deserves it. But that's how we are.

Comment: Copypasta straight into thesis:(

Comment: I don’t understand the sawtooth explanation: what are the bins, and why are they of unequal lengths for that part of the curve but not later points of the curve?

Comment: @DanBron you're right, thanks. What I mentioned only plays a role at higher levels of reputation, above 100. Now that I think of it again, it has a different cause.

Comment: That last point...

Comment: I wish [axes would be labeled](https://xkcd.com/833/).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I love SEDE - so many interesting insights.

Comment: If you don't want to buy the book, [this article in Forbes magazine](https://www.forbes.com/sites/joshbersin/2014/02/19/the-myth-of-the-bell-curve-look-for-the-hyper-performers/#161b3d336bca) is a sufficient summary.

Comment: Also [explained](http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/833:_Convincing).

Comment: Well, I was right. SO "reputation" is nothing like the normal distribution one would expect from a natural social measure (reputation is a social measure).  The graph given has been cleverly transformed with logarithmic scaling to appear to be more natural, but it does not take much cognition to see that the distribution is unnatural, becoming especially corrupted in the higher echelons. It is truly a mispresentation to call this "reputation" or anything else other than "fantasy nerd points".

Comment: I’d expect any reliable measure of real-world reputation (if it exists at all) to be distributed in a similar way as here, just like concepts as ‘wealth’, ‘book sales by author’ and (pardon the example) ‘casualties per shooting’.

Comment: Those are excellent examples of other false measures of reputation. Except the last one, which is obscene and unacceptable. Pardon denied.

Comment: @DominicCerisano Because it should only be called "reputation" if it's normally distributed? What about, for example, the distribution of belt colours in Karate? Are they normally distributed?

Comment: @DominicCerisano: it is a *statistic*, one that follows the same kind of distribution as reputation on this site. Please don't be hyperbolic.

Comment: @DominicCerisano Reputation - here and other sites (say reddit) - aren't going to be normally distributed. Reputation is based on many factors one of which is "time spent doing a thing". Everyone who joins SO starts at 1 rep. Everyone. Millions of them. Over time, some of those users add content, post questions or answers, and generally participate in the site. Their reputation goes up as they do this. As time goes on, users decide to stay (or not) and continue to add content. If they leave, their reputation becomes pretty static. If they stay and add content, their reputation increases.

Comment: The slope of this increase depends on the value of their contributions, as judged by the community. There is *no way* reputation can be normally distributed here. There is an overwhelming majority of users that have 1 rep, because that's what everyone starts with. The number of users with higher and higher reputation values drops because fewer people put in the time required to gain that reputation value.

Comment: It is obvious that the bell curve in the question is not going to apply to SO rep.  The OP knew that before the question was posted.  The normal distribution was posted in order to engineer SO users to do statistical anaysis work for no wages and to provide a platform for further trolling.  We should not have fallen for it.

Comment: Considering that the SO business model is job placement (global labour traffic),  misrepresenting gamified scoring as  "Reputation" is more than mere sophism. Its right up there with Facebook calling it's bathroom wall a "News Feed", or Bitcoin calling a Ponzi scheme "Currency".

Comment: The sawtooth is due to reputation typically increasing by 10 at a time.  This effect is hidden by the larger binning (due to the logarithmic scale) as the plot moves to the right, and also reduced on the right, as a percentage, by the increasing likelihood of having earned (or lost) points in other multiples. 
 Here's a view with linear binning by multiples of 10: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1084693/reputation-distribution-linear-scale#graph

Comment: Similar result found on Mathematics: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21259/distribution-of-reputation-power-law