# What's the reputation score of the first decile in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, reputation, statistics

I was wondering what the structure and the repartition of reputation on Stack Overflow is?

A list of interesting questions:

- What's the average reputation per user?
- What's the standard deviation?
- What's the reputation of the first decile of users?

Ideally, a tool like [op.gg](https://op.gg) would be welcome, with a split per language, tag, and country.

Comment: The vast majority of users have 1 reputation, so that would hideously shmoosh the results unless you factor that in somehow... But what's the use case?

Comment: Pure curiosity! As well as understanding `reputation` management from Stack top management.. May be interesting regarding other fields of study, mainly Economy, Sociology and Politics.

Comment: You shouldn't be using blockquote formatting for something that's not a quote. Nor code formatting for something that's not code. And the book reference is quite irrelevant in this context. And the site's name is "Stack Overflow", not "StackOverflow". No need to link to it, we know what site you are talking about. Tried to help you with an edit, but I see you rolled it back. Suit yourself.

Comment: I've seen your edit yivi, but I found it ugly, and unreadable. Thanks though for suggestion. Furthermore, I don't consider any book illustration as irrelevant.

Comment: You can dig up this information for yourself using the public data dump, available on the Data Explorer. Also see the very related questions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281147/whats-the-average-reputation-on-stack-overflow and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272749/distribution-of-reputation-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's rather easy to get this information from the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) - that is when you know how `PERCENTILE_CONT` works and why they made the decision to have it [return multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29337496/4751173).

[This SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1072040/reputation-statistics) tells you the answers:

- Average reputation: 107.25
- Standard deviation: 2307.07
- First decile: 50

A split per language, tag or country is more difficult for various reasons: the daily reputation cap makes it harder to find out for which tag(s) users earned reputation; not everybody has their country in their profile, etc.

Note that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning. Feel free to [fork](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/fork/1072040) the query to experiment, and take the awesome [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) if you're new to SEDE or SQL in general.

A while ago, I created [a nice graph](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357336/4751173) showing the reputation distribution on a log-log scale. It does bear some resemblance to the distribution of wealth in the real world.

[image: People always talk about, reputation. I don't care about your other graphs, just be good to me.]

The logarithms are base-10, so the 2.0 on the x-axis corresponds to 10<sup>2</sup> = 100 reputation and there are about 10<sup>4</sup> = 10,000 users with this much reputation.

Comment: Awesome!! The last question asked also gathered -59 downvotes, for some strange reasons... What is the abscissa and ordinate legend? What's the red arrow representing ?

Comment: That question gathered so many downvotes since it started with a false premise and an author who insisted they were right. I'll update the answer with a legend.